# Can anyone identify this clever short tale of two explorers who start hallucinating a monster on their return to earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Two explorers become aware there is a monster on their ship as they return to earth from a new planet. They retreat section by section but every attempt to block it fails until they are trapped in the sleeping quarters. They then realise there must have been a chemical on the planet which causes them to hallucinate but they know that if your brain thinks you been killed then you are good as dead.I won't spoil the ending for anyone who hasn't read it.
I recall vaguely that the author had written other clever short stories.

Comment: I'm newish here and need to see where it says it's OK for spoilers. It's such a nice ending. Is there a private message way ?

Comment: Never mind, I think your story is "Ghost V" by Robert Sheckley.

Comment: You can read it at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/galaxymagazine-1954-10) Is that the one?

Comment: @user14111 You should know to publish this as an answer, as comments are not searchable.

Comment: Huh. I thought that it was to link it together in the system. Which, as you note, does make it more likely that it will pop up as a suggestion.

Comment: And I do apologize. I could have phrased my comment to possibly leave an answer in a more diplomatic manner.

Comment: I suspect @user14111 is correct. Interesting how a distant memory is distorted. I have got it from the archive and will read it so am OK if this post is deleted.
That's now 3 very old stories I've described  sketchily and inaccurately yet they've been identified ! Thanks people !

Comment: @ColinKerr You're welcome! Your question won't be deleted, it's just marked "duplicate" and linked to an older question. But it sounds like you're not quite sure this is the right story. Please come back and comment again after you've read it, if this is for sure the right story (so we can close the question) or not (so we keep looking).